# django not cleaning up previous data

Tags: django

I have a django setup which does not include any models or data base. It is just simple HTML, JAVAscript and python. It seems like django is not cleaning up the previous run data. How to cleanup data from forms after every run? I am not making use of sessions also. I am new to django and don;t have much time to learn sessions and implement things. Can any one give a solution on how to cleanup data after every run?

Comment: Please show us some code

Comment: So you just created the form using html and javascript.

Comment: Yes.. I have not used models or database

Comment: One thing I noticed is, I have to kill runserver to cleanup the previous data and start runsever again in nohup.

Comment: I will explain the flow @Jacek:

1. From html, take the form data and send to javascript.
2. Using AJAX (in javascript), call python (views.py)
3. Get respose back with "return render" that is HTML file response
4. And in ajax, display the HTML rendered file on the same HTML, which was submitted

Comment: I am answering blindly... just create new form after return render `form = YourForm()`

Comment: But I don;t have any forms created using forms.py

Comment: Seems like django is not handling dictionaries well. I mean, its not clearing the old entry. I am manually adding clear.

Answer (score 0):

Use clear method to remove dictionary elements. Because django holds old values too. Not sure why, but this isn't the case with normal python scripts.

Answer (score 0):

you have to clean the form via javascript than. The code below might get you some idea.

```
  <body>
  <form id="newForm">
     Student Name<br><input type="text" name="sname"><br>
     Student Subject<br><input type="password" name="ssubject"><br>
     <input type="button" onclick="clear()" value="Submit">
  </form>
  <script>
     function clear() {
        document.getElementById("newForm").reset();
     }
  </script>
```